# Handling errors in flat file reader

Tags: spring-batch

(im new to spring batch sorry for dumb question but google is not showing me an example)

I have a batch job that is kicked off by quartz daily at midnight.  The job tries to read one or more flat files and processes them.  Sometimes the file the job reads is NOT where it needs to be.  so getting FileNotFoundException.  We would like to email the production support team that the required data file was not available.

I think something along the lines of the following is the preferred way to do that in springbatch.  Am I correct or is there a better way.  Should my notifyProdSupLister in the batch:chunk statement?

```
<batch:step id="readDataFileStep" next="processDataFileStep">
        <batch:listeners>
              <batch:listner ref="notifyProdSupListner"/>
        </batch:listeners>
        <batch:tasklet .....>
            <batch:chunk reader="stagedDataReader" processor="extractProcessor"
                writer="extractOutputWriter" commit-interval="1">
                <batch:listeners>
                    <batch:listener ref="chunkListener" />
                </batch:listeners>
            </batch:chunk>
        </batch:tasklet>
    </batch:step>
```

I am assuming my listner would look something like 
package com.mkyong.listeners;

```
public class notifyProdSupListner implements ItemReadListener<Domain> {

@Override
public void onReadError(Exception ex) {
    if (ex instanceof FileNotFoundException) {
        //mail support group
    }

}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I discovered that what I want to do can't be done that way.  I have job launcher and the job launcher won't launch the job unless there is an input file and it is readable.

While the ItemReadListener would allow me to do things if their was a problem reading the file. Because there was no input file, the launcher would have never started the job in the first place

Answer (score 1):

In FlatFileItemReader (I hope that's what you are using) you can set property strict=false if you dont want to fail job in case source is not present. and for your case you can keep it true(which is default value, it will throw IllegalStateException which your can catch through JobExecutionListener in afterJob. There you will get JobExecution from which you can get getAllFailureExceptions() and check if it failed for the reason that file dont exist. and then do what ever you want to do for handling it.